# iOS: Button action for different tag ids and avoiding switch case program

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am developing an iOS app screen, where i'm having around 25 buttons, clicking on each button will launch a separate view controller. Basically, i have implemented like having one 'IBAction' and provide 'tag id' for each button. Under this button action, based on button tag id, i am launching each view controller. **Problem here is, i'm programming via `switch case` for identifying this button id's, but i want to avoid using this switch case and looking to provide more efficient programming here.** How it is possible to remove 'switch case' but provide better way of programming for this situation.

Comment: From what I read from your question, your method of giving tags to button and branching using switch case is the best method itself.. What alternative you want?

Comment: Is there any similarity with the names of the ViewControllers to be launched? If all are different then you might have to use switch case itself.

Comment: In case your viewcontroller names viewcontroller1, viewcontroller2 etc.. you could have used it as - (IBAction)tappedButton:(UIButton *)sender{
    NSString *viewControllerClassString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"viewcontroller%d",sender.tag];
    id viewController = [[NSClassFromString(viewControllerClassString) alloc] init];

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here a `switch` statement seems to be the cleanest and most efficient way to do things, you could have a big `if-elseif` but if you're giving the cold shoulder to `switch` then that's even less of an option for you I guess.

If you really want to avoid a switch then what you could do is tag your buttons from 0 to 24, and have an `NSArray` containing an array of the names of your view controller's class, then use `NSClassFromString` to get the class reference from which to instantiate an object of that class.

Then you could do something like:

```
- (id)init{
    self = [super init];
    if(self){
        self.classesArray = @[@"MyControllerOne", @"MyControllerTwo", @"MyControllerThree"];
    }
    return self;
}

[...]

- (IBAction)tappedButton:(UIButton *)sender{
    NSString *viewControllerClassString = [self.classesArray objectAtIndex:sender.tag];
    id viewController = [[NSClassFromString(viewControllerClassString) alloc] init];

    // Present it modally? Push it onto the stack? 
}
```